# create a instance once and then just edit from there

Tags: javascript

so I am currently programming a app and I ran into a problem were I want it to only create one instance of the discord invite after someone enters it and then from there on out it edits the discord invite when you put in a new input. The problem is it creates a instance of the discord invite each time you submit a new value. How do I make it so that you only have to enter a value once and then from there on out, it edits the discord invite each time there is a new value? Thanks

```js
if (socialsChooser.value === "discord") {
  var a = document.getElementById("discordJoin");
  var linkText = document.createTextNode("Discord Invite")
  a.appendChild(linkText)
  a.title = "Discord Invite Link";
  a.href = `${inputInvite.value}`;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could check for children count and add if the `discordJoin` doesn't have text

```
        const a = document.getElementById("discordJoin");
        if(a.children.length === 0) {
          const linkText = document.createTextNode("Discord Invite")
          a.appendChild(linkText)
        } 
        a.title = "Discord Invite Link";
        a.href = `${inputInvite.value}`;
```

Since the `a` already in the document, you dont need to append it again, so removed the last line  `document.body.appendChild(a);`

Comment: Nope, still have the same problem as before. nothing has changed